# Convert Image list to Image array

Tags: c#, arrays, image, list

looked at a few examples , Following the examples my code now looks like this (See Below) , However unfortunately I'm getting the error 
"'System.Windows.Forms.ImageList' does not contain a definition for 'toArray' and no extension method 'toArray' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.ImageList' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Any ideas ? I may have missed a part shown in other posts but i dont think so

```
ImageList Move_list = new ImageList();
.
.
.
//Gather the images
string        path          = "C:/Pictures/Movements/User";
string[]      filter        = { ".jpg", ".jpeg"};
DirectoryInfo directoryInfo = new DirectoryInfo(path);
FileInfo[]    fileInfo      = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
ArrayList     arrayList     = new ArrayList();

foreach (FileInfo fi in fileInfo)
  foreach (string s in filter)
    if (s == fi.Extension)
      arrayList.Add(fi.FullName);

//adding files to image list:
for (i = 0; i < arrayList.Count; i++)
{
  System.Drawing.Image img = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(arrayList[i].ToString());
  Move_list.Images.Add(img);
}

User_moves[0] =  Move_list.toArray();
```

Comment: More detail, please. You haven't told us the data types for `Move_list`, or `Move_list.Images`, it's rather hard to tell you how to turn it into an array. It *looks* like your class `Move_list` has some sort of `Images` collection. If that is `IEnumerable<Image>`, you can simply say `Image[] x = Move_list.ToArray() ;`

Comment: Sorry about that , the move list is : ImageList Move_list = new ImageList();

Answer (score 3):

Move_list.Images is your list, not the ImageList.  It's a badly named class, but it maps up with ImageList concept in Win32 (which was a handle on a long bitmap of sequencial images).  Anyway:

```
Move_list.Images.Cast<Image>().ToArray();
```

Comment: If you don't use the Cast, you get an object[] instead of an Image[].

Comment: no luck , doin that throws this error : 'System.Data.EnumerableRowCollectionExtensions.Cast<TResult>(System.Data.EnumerableRowCollection)' is a 'method', which is not valid in the given context

Comment: My bad, I forgot the brackets on the Cast<Image>() call.

Answer (score 0):

From what I gather, `Move_list` is an `ImageList`. `ImageList` does not implement `IQueryable` or `IEnumerable`. `ToArray` is defined in `System.Linq` as an extension method on those two interfaces.

You should be able to use `Move_list.Images.ToArray()`, since Images is an `ImageCollection`, which does implement `IEnumerable`.